# Google App Engine and backends: how to configure it on development server?

Tags: google-app-engine

My configuration of `backends.yaml`

```
backends:
- name: mybackend
  class: B1
  instances: 1
  options: dynamic
```

and `app.yaml`

```
handlers:
- url: http://mybackend.myapp.appspot.com
  script: mybackend.py
  login: admin
```

Running it localy on development server I get this error:

> Unable to assign value 'http://mybackend.myapp.appspot.com' to attribute 'url':
>   Value 'http://mybackend.myapp.appspot.com' for url does not match expression '^(?!\^)/|.|((.).*(?!\$).$'

How can I test backend on development server?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I believe the url should be the relative url from your site.  The script should be the python function that's run, not the filename.  So your app.yaml should be.

```
handlers:
- url: /backend
  script: mybackend.myfunction
  login: admin
```

Your backend and frontend instances share the same handlers, there's no way to distinguish between them.

Comment: But how than the engine recognize that the url '/backend' should be run as backend instance?

Comment: If you make a request to http://mybackend.myapp.appspot.com/backend, it'll run on the backend instance.  If you make a request to http://myapp.appspot.com/backend, it'll run on a normal instance and time out.  That's why you want to set login:admin (which you did properly).  In theory the admin will only make a non-backend request at http://myapp.appspot.com/backend if they know what they're doing.  In your /backend handler, you can detect whether you're actually on a backend and act appropriately.  See the backend API http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/backends/functions.html

Comment: Thx, now it is clear. I read properly the documentation before I post the question here, however even now I have to say it is written non-intuitively (at least for me).

Comment: Yes, I totally agree. I have found it very difficult to see how the handler got assigned to a backend instead of a frontend. The comment above from dragonx makes it much more clear now. Thanks!